# How to measure gap/opening length of an object in an image?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to find the gap length of this object.

[image]

Currently, I'm only able to measure it manually using image processing software.

[image]

Any ideas or links to posts that could assist in solving this question are appreciated.

Comment: You could compute the convex hull, then find the longest contiguous section of border edges that are in the black area. It's not exactly the same as the red line you drew, but it's also not clear why you drew the line in exactly that place.

Comment: It might also be helpful to see a few more examples of possible inputs and desired outputs. Generalizing from just one image is hard.

Comment: Maybe you can divide the image two parts as up and down. you can find first value from letf to right for two parts using for loop. These are our left and gap points. After that you can use euclidian distance to measure this distance.